# .NET Core Docker Image for SPA Applications

Tags: node.js, docker, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

What is the correct Docker image to use when creating a new ASP.NET Core MVC app, specifically with the React/Redux (or other Node.js required) template? If not a specific image, what commands or process should be followed in the Dockerfile for a Node.js app backed by ASP.NET Core MVC?

I don't require the SDK version of the framework for anything other than running the backing MVC site.

`dotnet new reactredux`

The runtime image does not have Node.js installed, and will error when trying to run the container.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:latest

ARG source=./bin/Debug/netcoreapp2.0/publish/
WORKDIR /app
COPY $source .

EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Project.dll"]
```

Error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Failed to start Node process. To resolve this:.

[1] Ensure that Node.js is installed and can be found in one of the PATH directories.
    Current PATH enviroment variable is: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
    Make sure the Node executable is in one of those directories, or update your PATH.
```

The project I am working with is being upgraded from ASP.NET MVC for .NET Standard 1.1 (standalone), to a new .NET Standard 2.0 React/Redux project.

Comment: I assume you have a .NET Core backend for your API and the index.html is being served by a Node service like Express?

Comment: A better way would be to spin up 2 containers for each (Node.js and ASP.NET Core) and make them communicate via a docker network.

Comment: @Brad Yes, but for the sake of the example, I'm using the `dotnet new reactredux` template, which creates an ASP.NET MVC application, in which the default route serves the React app.

Comment: @JanshairKhan Agreed, but I wanted to get it running "out of the box" with the `dotnet new template`.

Comment: The answer is flagged a duplicate, but I found it far more helpful for solving this problem, while the answers here confused me:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45880460/enable-docker-support-for-angular-project

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem is that the base image in your dockerfile (microsoft/aspnetcore:latest) does not have node installed.

So you have to install node so you can run the project. This is the dockerfile I came up with:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
ARG source
EXPOSE 80 5102
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:80
RUN apt-get -qq update && apt-get -qqy --no-install-recommends install wget gnupg \
    git \
    unzip

RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x |  bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
WORKDIR /app
COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Project.dll"]
```

Notice how on line 5 of the dockerfile I'm running a command to update apt-get. And then in line 8-9 node is installed to the docker image

There is still a problem, hot module replacement from webpack does not work. Not even a full refresh works. I'm still looking in to it.

**UPDATE:**
so I looked into the hot module replacement problem, and it appears to be a [limitation of docker for windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/troubleshoot/#workarounds).

The workaround is to configure webpack so it can tell the browser to poll for changes on a determined amount of time. [See this link to see how to configure it](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/#watchoptions)

**UPDATE:**
Doing a little more research I found out that microsoft has an image you can use to build your project, it is called: microsoft/aspnetcore-build. This image has all the dependencies you need for building (including nodejs).

So at the end, what I did was leave my Dockerfile as it was (with microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 as base image), and created a new Dockerfile for development which references the build image I mentioned before. With the help of docker compose I switch Dockerfiles depending on the environment.

This approach seems more convenient because when images are deployed to production environment they should have all its javascript code ready (in the case of a spa application with angular 2, react, etc), in other words they should not have a nodejs dependency, making them less heavy in size.

Comment: Cool, so including it via apt-get is the way to go then. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Can you share the file to switch between Dockerfiles?

Comment: `microsoft/aspnetcore-build` doesn't contain the latest version of the SDK, I'm using 2.2 version I get the same error.

Comment: Note that `microsoft/aspnetcore-build` has been [officially deprecated](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/292). See the migration steps for 2.1 and newer: https://github.com/aspnet/aspnet-docker/tree/master/2.1

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Daniels answer above, running Visual Studio 2017 v15.4 and ASP.NET Core 2.0 on Docker, here are the changes you need to make to allow correct Production and Development behavior for SPA applications (in my case I'm using Angular):

- Add a new Dockerfile to your project which is a copy of the original.  Lets call it Dockerfile.Development.  Modify as follows:

  ```
  FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
  ARG source

  # BEGIN MODIFICATION - Node is needed for development (but not production)
  RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash -
  RUN apt-get install --assume-yes nodejs
  # END MODIFICATION

  WORKDIR /app
  EXPOSE 80
  COPY ${source:-obj/Docker/publish} .
  ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyService.dll"]
  ```
- Modify the docker-compose.override.yml file in your solution to use this new dockerfile in development.  It'll look something like this:

  ```
  version: '3'

  services:
    myservice:
      environment:
        - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      ports:
        - "80"
      build:
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.Development
  ```
- Modify the webpack.config.js file in your project to enable watching for changes, as follows:

  ```
  const clientBundleConfig = merge(sharedConfig, {
    entry: { 'main-client': './ClientApp/boot.browser.ts' },
    output: { path: path.join(__dirname, clientBundleOutputDir) },
    // BEGIN MODIFICATION
    watch: isDevBuild,
    watchOptions: {
      poll: isDevBuild ? 1000 : false
    },
    // END MODIFICATION
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({
          context: __dirname,
          manifest: require('./wwwroot/dist/vendor-manifest.json')
      })
    ].concat(isDevBuild ? [
  ```

Comment: If you re-read his answer you'll notice the recommendation to use microsoft/aspnetcore-build for development so you don't need to install nodejs in the dev Dockerfile.

Comment: What do you do about the UseWebpackDevMiddleware() call in Startup.cs?  I get the same error even after modifying the webpack.config.js file.

Comment: @ChrisHaines microsoft/aspnetcore-build was deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

I got the Angular example template to work simply by installing nodejs into the base:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0 AS base
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
    apt-get install -y gnupg2 && \
    wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
... rest of Dockerfile ...
```

Everything else (Webpack Hot swap) didn't throw an error.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to add just the `node` binary to your image you can copy what the `microsoft/aspnetcore-build` dockerfile does:

```
ENV NODE_VERSION 6.10.3

RUN set -ex \
  && for key in \
    9554F04D7259F04124DE6B476D5A82AC7E37093B \
    94AE36675C464D64BAFA68DD7434390BDBE9B9C5 \
    0034A06D9D9B0064CE8ADF6BF1747F4AD2306D93 \
    FD3A5288F042B6850C66B31F09FE44734EB7990E \
    71DCFD284A79C3B38668286BC97EC7A07EDE3FC1 \
    DD8F2338BAE7501E3DD5AC78C273792F7D83545D \
    B9AE9905FFD7803F25714661B63B535A4C206CA9 \
    C4F0DFFF4E8C1A8236409D08E73BC641CC11F4C8 \
  ; do \
    gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys "$key" || \
    gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key" || \
    gpg --keyserver keyserver.pgp.com --recv-keys "$key" ; \
  done

# set up node
RUN buildDeps='xz-utils' \
    && set -x \
    && apt-get update && apt-get install -y $buildDeps --no-install-recommends \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && curl -SLO "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" \
    && curl -SLO "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/SHASUMS256.txt.asc" \
    && gpg --batch --decrypt --output SHASUMS256.txt SHASUMS256.txt.asc \
    && grep " node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz\$" SHASUMS256.txt | sha256sum -c - \
    && tar -xJf "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 \
    && rm "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" SHASUMS256.txt.asc SHASUMS256.txt \
    && apt-get purge -y --auto-remove $buildDeps \
    && ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/nodejs
```

This adds about ~42 MB to your image vs ~157 MB using `apt-get`.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you're running ASP.NET Core 3.0 the base images from Microsoft still does not contain NodeJS. You must install NodeJS by yourself. Luckily it's not *that* hard.

Here's how I solved it recently. Please note the Dockerfile is more like pseudo-code than fully functional, I stripped away most noise. It's installing version 10 of NodeJS, you can of course change that. [Here are different node distributions you can install](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions).

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.0-buster AS build

# Install NodeJS 10
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN npm install
RUN npm run test-docker
RUN npm run build

RUN dotnet restore...

RUN dotnet test...

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Collector.Forms.Autogiro.Web.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Your.Web.dll"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an easy way to containerize SPA applications:

First, we have to comment this two lines in csproj file in your application because it force us to install NodeJS in a docker container.

```
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm install" />
<Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm run build" />
```

Next, inside container, you only need ASP.NET Core runtime for running your application. However a Node Docker image is used for compile React client application. So you need a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM node as build-node
WORKDIR /ClientApp
# ClientApp folder contains all your react code
COPY MyApp/ClientApp/package.json .
COPY MyApp/ClientApp/package-lock.json .
RUN npm install
COPY MyApp/ClientApp/ . 
# This command will generate build folder
RUN npm run build

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 AS build
WORKDIR /app
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
COPY *.sln .

# In next step you'll get an error if you didn't comment two lines mentioned above in csproj file
COPY MyApp/MyApp.csproj ./MyApp 
RUN dotnet restore
COPY MyApp/. ./MyApp
WORKDIR /app/MyApp
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app

# Here we get compile result from .net core application
COPY --from=build /app/MyApp/out ./

# Here we  get compile result for React app
COPY --from=build-node /ClientApp/build ./ClientApp/build

# Application port
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyApp.dll"]
```