# Enable Docker support for Angular project

Tags: angular, docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

Is there a way in Visual Studio 2017 to automatically enable Docker support for an asp.net-core **Angular** project? The option is disabled when creating a new one. It is only available for *Web Application (MVC)*.

I am able to Enable Docker support (Project->Add->Docker Support) for the angular project after I have created the project, but when I start the application I get an exception that node.js is not available.

> System.AggregateException occurred   HResult=0x80131500   Message=One
>   or more errors occurred. (Failed to start Node process. To resolve
>   this:.
>
> [1] Ensure that Node.js is installed and can be found in one of the
>   PATH directories.
>       Current PATH enviroment variable is: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
>       Make sure the Node executable is in one of those directories, or update your PATH.
>
> [2] See the InnerException for further details of the cause.)
>   Source=   StackTrace:    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean
>   waitCompletionNotification)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebpackDevMiddleware.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(IApplicationBuilder
>   appBuilder, WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions options)    at
>   WebApplication3.Startup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app,
>   IHostingEnvironment env) in
>   C:\Users\temp\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2017\Projects\WebApplication3\Startup.cs:line 34
>
> Inner Exception 1: InvalidOperationException: Failed to start Node
>   process. To resolve this:.
>
> [1] Ensure that Node.js is installed and can be found in one of the
>   PATH directories.
>       Current PATH enviroment variable is: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
>       Make sure the Node executable is in one of those directories, or update your PATH.
>
> [2] See the InnerException for further details of the cause.
>
> Inner Exception 2: Win32Exception: No such file or directory

If it is not possible to create it automatically how can I manually get the Docker support enabled for my Angular project?

Comment: You will need to install it on top of the base image. See if these links help https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation/tree/dc7c8721797ddde0c428de0692b22ca6a9bcfa09/windows-server-container-samples/node-v0.12.7-x64 and https://stefanscherer.github.io/create-an-io-js-container-image-for-windows/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I solved my problem.

I needed to install nodejs also on my image, cause it is needed by webpack. I have changed my Dockerfile to also install nodejs version 6

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
    apt-get install -y gnupg2 && \
    wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs
# Rest of Dockerfile
```

Using only `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nodejs` was not enough, cause this installs version 4 of nodejs and it was installed in folder `nodejs`, so that the `WebpackDevMiddleware` did not find the node executable.

Comment: I got this to work by adding it to the [base] definition, not later ones.  Has to be against Microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0.

Comment: This TOTALLY solved my issue thank u!!!!!