# How can I run a VS2017 Angular project in a Linux Docker container?

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

**NOTE**: there are several questions about this topic already, which I reference below. While this question is in that sense a duplicate, I have tried to follow the advice in those other questions without success. Sometimes that's because the answer now refers to an out-of-date version of the relevant packages, and sometimes because it's not clear exactly how to implement the changes.

This question is my attempt to document a minimal, (non-)working example, with full instructions of how to reproduce the issue. Hopefully I can update it with similarly clear instructions on how to fix it.

---

I have the following environment:

- **Windows 10** (enterprise, 1709)
- **VS2017** (15.8.4)
- **Node** (11.5)
- **Angular CLI** (7.1.4)
- **Docker Desktop** (community, 2.0.0.2)

Here are the exact steps I followed to create an Angular SPA project:

> Create a directory for the project

```
md MyAngularWebsite
cd MyAngularWebsite
```

> Create the project using the `dotnet` CLI (using the Angular template)

```
dotnet new angular
```

If I open this solution in VS, I see all the files I'd expect to see:

[image]

...and if I run it (in IIS Express) it works as expected:

[image]

So far, so good.

> Add Docker support

[*Note: although I created the project via the .NET CLI, it's also possible to create projects using the Visual Studio UI. When doing this, there's an "Add Docker Support" checkbox in the new-project dialog. However, that checkbox is disabled for Angular projects. Presumably this is because it doesn't work. We can however get halfway there using the following method.*]

I right-clicked on the website project (`MyAngularWebsite`), and chose "Add Docker Support" from the pop-up menu.

Visual Studio asks for the type of Operating System that the Docker image will use - I chose Linux:

[image]

This seems to do two things:

1. Adds a file named `Dockerfile` to the project.
2. Adds a new profile named "Docker" to `Properties\launchSettings.json`

Here's the contents of `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 14242
EXPOSE 44321

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyAngularWebsite.csproj", ""]
RUN dotnet restore "/MyAngularWebsite.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/"
RUN dotnet build "MyAngularWebsite.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyAngularWebsite.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyAngularWebsite.dll"]
```

Now, if I start the project using the new "Docker" launch profile, there's a long pause while it downloads and builds all the required parts, and then a docker container is created, and a browser window is launched pointing to `https://localhost:44321/`.

It's at this point that we see an error saying **`Failed to start 'npm'`**:

[image]

Having read [many](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50859980/98422) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45880460/98422) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45700361/98422) about this, I gather that the issue is simply that the base image (in this case `microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime` as specified at the top of the `Dockerfile`) does not include Node.

Node is required so that the Angular app can be built, since `ng build` is what's used to build it - and that relies on Node. (Although I have Node on my local machine, it's not on the Docker image on which the app is being built).

So, the suggested approach is to add Node to the Docker image by modifying the `Dockerfile`.

> Add Node to the Docker image

As suggested in the questions referenced above, I modified the `Dockerfile` to include the following:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
    apt-get install -y gnupg2 && \
    wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs
```

This means that my full `Dockerfile` now looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS base

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
    apt-get install -y gnupg2 && \
    wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | bash - && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential nodejs

WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 14242
EXPOSE 44321

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["MyAngularWebsite.csproj", ""]
RUN dotnet restore "/MyAngularWebsite.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/"
RUN dotnet build "MyAngularWebsite.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "MyAngularWebsite.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyAngularWebsite.dll"]
```

...and... *the results are exactly the same*.

> Why is NPM not installed?

Per @DannyB's comment, I tried bash-ing into the Docker container to run `npm` directly:

```
docker exec -it mycontainer_id /bin/bash
```

...and when I tried to execute `npm` I got an error saying "**npm: command not found**". So, I guess that's the reason that it's still not working.

I then tried executing each of the commands I added to the `Dockerfile` in turn, directly in the bash shell. When I got to the line:

```
wget -qO- https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x
```

...it executed without producing any output, but I realised that's because the `-q` flag means "quiet mode", so I executed it again without the `q`. This time, I got errors:

```
ERROR: The certificate of 'deb.nodesource.com' is not trusted.
ERROR: The certificate of 'deb.nodesource.com' hasn't got a known issuer.
```

Digging deeper, it turns out I get certificate-related errors even if I simply do:

```
curl https://www.google.com
```

This results in an error saying "SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain".

So, it seems that my container has trust issues :-).

> Why is my container unable to make HTTPS connections?

Per [this question](http://SSL%20certificate%20problem:%20self%20signed%20certificate%20in%20certificate%20chain), it seems that it's because I'm running in a corporate environment where SSL traffic through the firewall is intercepted/re-encrypted, and that I'll need to configure my Docker container to trust the corresponding certificate.

Assuming that's correct, hopefully I'll be able to fix the trust issues, then install NPM, and *hopefully* solve the original issue.

I think this question has moved rather off-topic now, though I'll continue to update it if I manage to make further progress.

Comment: Have you tried installing node on the second Docker build step? When `bash`ing into the container - can you run `npm` ?

Comment: This maybe a stupid question but did you rebuild the image after making changes to the Dockerfile?

Comment: @DannyB: yes, I tried that - no luck. I've not tried bash - I will on Monday.

Comment: @dongi: Yes, I did.

Comment: @DannyB: I tried using `bash` to run `npm` within the container - no luck, it's not there. I've updated this question, but I'll deal with the can't-install-npm issue as a separate question to avoid polluting this one. Thanks.

Comment: In my _opinion_ the issue is with the template. It has the Angular app inside the .NET solution.  I have seen it done 'right', where the Angular App is in it's very own container (usually alpine or carbon) and the .NET Core back-end is in a second container.  You can wire these two up with docker compose.

Answer (score 0):

My working DockerFile has an npm install for npm after the apt-gets.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.2-stretch-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2-stretch AS build
RUN apt-get update -yq && apt-get upgrade -yq && apt-get install -yq curl git nano
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - && apt-get install -yq nodejs build-essential
RUN npm install -g npm
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
WORKDIR /src/PAP.UI
COPY . PAP.UI.csproj
RUN dotnet restore "PAP.UI.csproj"
COPY . .
RUN dotnet build "PAP.UI.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "PAP.UI.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PAP.UI.dll"]
```