# Installing Erlang via asdf on Ubuntu fails after "Downloading kerl"

Tags: erlang, asdf-vm

### Background

I have a Ubuntu and I am trying to install Erlang 22.2.8 via the [asdf-erlang plugin](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-erlang).

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

### Problem

In fact, I want to install any version of Erlang, but none works.

```
$ asdf install erlang 22.2.8
Downloading kerl...
$
```

It stops after "Downloading kerl" and then nothing happens. It is like it finished.
I have followed the steps [before-asdf-install](https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf-erlang#before-asdf-install) also before installing the plugin, but non the less this does not prevent the error.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of investigation by me and several people from the Elixir community, we have finally discovered what was the issue.

### Issue

The first clue was the exit signal of the command itself:

```
$ asdf install erlang 22.2.8
Downloading kerl...
$ echo $?
1
```

The exit code is 1. Which means an error was occurring.

So after digging into the code, we found there was a curl call I was not able to make:

```
$ curl -v -Lso ~/.asdf/plugins/erlang/kerl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kerl/kerl/2.0.2/kerl
*   Trying 151.101.16.133:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to raw.githubusercontent.com (151.101.16.133) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [122 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
{ [6 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [3400 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS alert, unknown CA (560):
} [2 bytes data]
* SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
* Closing connection 0
```

I was having SSL certificate issues. This is happening because of the company VPN/Proxy.

A quickfix/workaround could be found using the `-k` option to allow the curl to connect to insecure connections. After trying that curl with `-k` the request succeeded, which proved the theory correct.

### Solution

With the issue identified, it was time to search for a solution. The solution I believe would be the most adequate, would be to add the company certificates to ssl certs.pem. This is described better in the following SO post:

[How to fix "SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54402673/how-to-fix-ssl-certificate-problem-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chai)

### Quick workaround

However, that solution didn't work me. So I eventually decided to go with the risky option, which was to use the `~/.curlrc`.

https://ec.haxx.se/cmdline/cmdline-configfile#default-config-file

After setting up this file and adding the `-k` option in it, it worked. I can now finally install the erlang versions I need.

It should be noted, **this is a risk**. In fact, **this is a workaround and not really a solution**.

However, for the time being, I will happily take it.

### History

This is a summary of the whole discussion I had with the Elixir community. If you are interested in the full process, you can check the post:

https://elixirforum.com/t/installing-erlang-via-asdf-on-ubuntu-fails-after-downloading-kerl/36806/25