# debugging a .net app locally allows me to call https://localhost:1234. Calling the same from docker container gives cert error

Tags: c#, docker, visual-studio, ssl, curl

I have an mvc app that I'm able to debug (vscode - hitting F5) and call https://localhost:1234/health/status from my windows box - even though I haven't explicitly set up any certs.

Now I'm trying to make the same call from inside an docker container (host network).  I'm getting the following error:

```
root@b0522cdd5597:/workspaces/test# curl https://host.docker.internal:1234/health/status
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self-signed certificate
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

What I've Tried

I tried to use the -k (and the --insecure) option in curl.  But it gives me this error:

```
root@b0522cdd5597:/workspaces/test# curl -k https://host.docker.internal:1234/health/status
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
<BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Hostname</h2>
<hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.</p>
</BODY></HTML>
```

That hasn't really resolved anything.  Presently, I'm reviewing this post to see if I can glean anything:

[How to fix "SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54402673/how-to-fix-ssl-certificate-problem-self-signed-certificate-in-certificate-chai)

I don't want to have to create a self cert if at all possible.

EDIT 1

I opened up a Terminal from inside vscode where my project is running and tried this:

```
PS C:\Users\me\src\widget\server> dotnet dev-certs https --check     
No valid certificate found.     PS 
PS C:\Users\me\src\widget\server> dotnet dev-certs https --check --trust     
No valid certificate found.
```

**EDIT 2**

I tried to play with IIS Express settings to allow localhost.
Specifically, I did this:

a) launched netsh in command window as admin
b) ran the following command:

```
netsh>http add urlacl url=https://localhost:1234/ user=everyone

URL reservation successfully added

netsh>
```

I am able to start visual studio.  Start debugging.
In the container I try to curl -k on the localhost, but now i get

```
 "Failed to connect to localhost port 1234 after 0 ms: connection refused"
```

I retried with the verbose option in curl and this is what I see:

```
root@b0522cdd5597:/workspaces/IntegrationTests# curl -kv https://localhost:1234/health/status     
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:1234...     
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 123 failed: Connection refused     
*   Trying ::1:1234...     
* Immediate connect fail for ::1: Cannot assign requested address     
* Failed to connect to localhost port 1234 after 0 ms: Connection refused     * Closing connection 0     curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 1234 after 0 ms: Connection refused     root@b0522cdd5597:/workspaces/IntegrationTests#
```

To eliminate the ipv6 element, I tried this:

```
root@b0522cdd5597:/workspaces/IntegrationTests# curl -kv --ipv4 https://localhost:1234/health/status     
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:1234...     
* connect to 127.0.0.1 port 1234 failed: Connection refused     
* Failed to connect to localhost port 1234 after 0 ms: Connection refused     
* Closing connection 0     curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 1234 after 0 ms: Connection refused
```

I tried add another entry in netsh:  https://127.0.0.1:1234 but that didn't fix the problem.  I get the same error.

Lastly, I tried to add in netsh just a generic entry like this:

Reserved URL            : https://+:1234/
User: \Everyone
Listen: Yes
Delegate: No
SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;WD)

But when I try to start my app in v studio after that, i get a generic error that IIS cannot start.
I have to remove the entry from netsh, and restart vstudio in order to get rid of the error.

**Edit 3**

as far as editing launchsettings.json, our team uses the following:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:39124/",
      "sslPort": 1234
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "health/status",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Widget.Server": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "https://localhost:1234/health/status",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:1234/"
    }
  }
}
```

I'm thinking of updating every spot that reads https://localhost:1234 to be https://host.docker.internal:1234.

**EDIT 4**

This is what I've got working so far:
I updated the applicationUrl and the ssLport

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:39124/",
      "sslPort": 1234
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "health/status",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Widget.Server": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "https://localhost:1234/health/status",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://host.docker.internal:1234/",
      "sslPort":44398
    }
  }
}
```

Then I had to update my applicationhost.config:

```
                <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:39124:localhost" />
                <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:1234:localhost" />                  
                <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="172.31.32.1:1234:*" />
```

Added the last binding entry.
172.31.32.1 is the Ipv4 address i get on the host when i do an ipconfig.

Then lastly, I start VS code as admin.
Then I'm able to do this from the container:

```
 root@b40e84b51354:/workspaces/IntegrationTests# curl -k https://172.31.32.1:1234/health/status
```

and It returns the results.

Comment: Did you install the developer certificate using the dotnet cli? `dotnet dev-certs https --check --trust` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-dev-certs That's probably what made that self-signed cert, which isn't trusted in the docker container.

Comment: @gunr2171 Pls see Edit 1 in my post.  I don't recall creating this dev cert.

Comment: So then what made the self-signed cert? Which one is it using?

Comment: @gunr2171 I think that's a part of the question / issue.  When I set up our mvc app in my dev environment, "it just works".  I don't ever recall being prompted to create self signed certs.  This is the first time I'm trying to call / consume the endpoints from a "machine" other than my windows box.

Comment: @dot in edit 2 everywhere you're using localhost should be docker.host.internal you need to configure your app to respond to that hostname, and you need to use that hostname to get to your app on the host from the container.

Comment: @NathanCarlson-MSFT when I update everything in edit 2 to be host.docker.internal, iis won't start from VS.

Comment: The specific error is "Unable to connect to web server 'IIS Express'.  As soon as I remove the https://host.docker.internal:1234 from the firewall and clean the cache, it starts working again.

Comment: @dot When using host.docker.internal, did you run VS as admin?

Comment: @NathanCarlson yeah... i'm running as admin.

Answer (score 0):

The cert issue is being by-passed by -k, the error you are getting is from a web server. I suspect you're running the app under IIS Express, as that was the only way I could repro this. That would also explain dotnet dev-certs not finding a cert as IIS express uses a different one.

Side note: If you want to check if you have a self-signed IIS cert here is a PowerShell one-liner:

```
Get-ChildItem Cert:\CurrentUser\Root\ | Where-Object FriendlyName -Like *IIS*
```

For fixing IIS Express handling an alternate host name see <del>Anton's solution here: [Bad Request - Invalid Hostname IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831097/bad-request-invalid-hostname-iis7)</del> (Edit: better option: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70104414/12567640)

You can also bypass this issue by running the app with dotnet run instead. That does require using dotnet dev-certs to setup a cert, but then worked for me being called from a container.

**Edit:**
Sorry cited the wrong answerer ‍♂️, but found a better answer anyway
Updating rnofenko's answer for the container usage looks like:

```
"iisSettings": {
  "windowsAuthentication": false,
  "anonymousAuthentication": true,
  "iisExpress": {
    "applicationUrl": "https://host.docker.internal:44392",
    "httpPort": 51222,
    "sslPort": 44392
  }
}
```

**Warning:**
Binding to host.docker.internal this way requires running VS as admin.

Comment: please see Edit2

Comment: please see Edit 3.

Comment: please see Edit 4

Answer (score 0):

I know you don't want to create a self-signed cert and seem satisfied with by-passing. But if you change your mind here is a sample that creates a self-signed cert that supports "localhost" and "host.docker.internal" : https://github.com/NCarlsonMSFT/CertExample